# Searching for certain mail addresses: The Method "Contains" is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, azure-active-directory

`using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient`, I want to get twenty accounts from Azure Active Directory; given their email addresses. I could now send twenty requests to the Azure AD server, but in the meantime, my script times out. So I tried a single request:

```
public override IEnumerable<IDirectoryEntry> GetEntriesForMails(IEnumerable<MailAddress> emails)
{
    foreach(IUser user in _connection.Client.Users.Where(x => emails.Contains(x.Mail)).FlattenPages())
    {
        yield return new AzureDirectoryEntry(user, this);
    }
```

This throws the error that

> "Contains" is not supported.

Is there another, supported, way to get all user accounts for twenty email addresses in a single round trip to the server?

Comment: What is the type of `user` in `_connection.Client.Users`?

Comment: Show the full exception with stack trace

Comment: Change `IEnumerable IDirectoryEntry` to `IEnumerable<IDirectoryEntry>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per a Microsoft employee, there is no direct solution in the library.

The best solution we could come up with is to keep a client-side lookup table that maps email adresses to ObjectIds; and update that table regularly (daily/weekly, and whenever a lookup failed).

One can then get the Objects for 20 ObjectIds from Azure AD in a single call (`GetObjectsByObjectIdsAsync` method).

Answer (score 0):

Try the code :

```
 List<IUser> users = activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
 List<IUser> user1 = users.Where(u => emails.Any(e => e.Contains(u.Mail))).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because my organization doesn't fit into `CurrentPage`, so I don't get all results. As I said, I want to search for multiple mail addresses server-side, so that the result fits on a single page - not fetch the whole directory from the server and then filter down client-side, which takes 20 pages of 100 addresses to fetch, and then I discard 99% of that. But such a search obviously is not supported.

Comment: My code is a general method, I am not sure there is official documents for what you want...